# Not adding the element in observable collection properly, id from past activity not passed properly

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I am new in Xamarin and I am making an app in which on screen 1 I am showing a list of Vehicle Makers, and on click of a certain maker represented in a collection view I am showing a list of their vehicles and there the user can change the manufacturers name and its abbreviation, and update it, delete the manufacturer, and add new vehicle to them. The problem is when I add the new vehicle, it doesn't seem to add to that manufacturer, its ID seems to be not defined. I am passing the id to the new view, but looks like I am not doing it right since the vehicle won't appear in the list  (when I turn off the vehicle manufacturer filter (comment the if (item.MakeId == itemId) in ExecuteLoadItemsCommand in VehicleMakeViewModel), I can see that the vehicle is added, but the id is not the one I want to set up, its empty.) I am probably doing something wrong or overlooking something, so please if you can see the issue, help me. In VehicleMakeViewModel I am doing the logic of adding new vehicles, removing and updating the manufacturer, and in NewVehicleModelViewModel I am letting the user type in info for the new vehicle.
VehicleMakeViewModel:

```
namespace App3.ViewModels
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(ItemId), nameof(ItemId))]
    public class VehicleMakeDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        private VehicleModel _selectedItem;

        public ObservableCollection<VehicleModel> VehicleModels { get; }
        public Command LoadVehicleModelsCommand { get; }
        public Command AddVehicleModelCommand { get; }

        public Command<VehicleModel> VehicleModelTapped { get; }

        public Command DeleteVehicleMakeCommand { get; }

        public Command UpdateVehicleMakeCommand { get; }

        public VehicleMakeDetailViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Vehicles";
            VehicleModels = new ObservableCollection<VehicleModel>();
            LoadVehicleModelsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

            VehicleModelTapped = new Command<VehicleModel>(OnVehicleModelSelected);

            AddVehicleModelCommand = new Command(OnAddItem);

            UpdateVehicleMakeCommand = new Command(UpdateItem);
            DeleteVehicleMakeCommand = new Command(DeleteItem);
        }

        async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                VehicleModels.Clear();
                var items = await BaseVehicleModelDataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    //if (item.MakeId == itemId)
                        VehicleModels.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }


        public void OnAppearing()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            SelectedItem = null;
        }
        public VehicleModel SelectedItem
        {
            get => _selectedItem;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
                OnVehicleModelSelected(value);
            }
        }

        async void OnVehicleModelSelected(VehicleModel item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                return;

            // This will push the ItemDetailPage onto the navigation stack
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(VehicleModelDetailPage)}?{nameof(VehicleModelDetailViewModel.ItemId)}={item.Id}");
        }

        private async void DeleteItem(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach(var item in VehicleModels)
                {
                    if (item.MakeId == Id)
                    {
                        await BaseVehicleModelDataStore.DeleteItemAsync(item.Id);
                    }
                }
                await BaseVehicleMakeDataStore.DeleteItemAsync(Id);
                
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(VehicleMakesPage));
                /*ItemId = "";
                VehicleMakeAbrv = "";
                VehicleMakeName = "";*/
                //App.Current.MainPage = new VehicleMakesPage();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        private async void UpdateItem(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                await BaseVehicleMakeDataStore.UpdateItemAsync(new VehicleMake { Id= Id, Name = VehicleMakeName, Abrv=VehicleMakeAbrv });
                foreach(var item in VehicleModels)
                {
                    if (item.MakeId == Id)
                    {
                        await BaseVehicleModelDataStore.UpdateItemAsync(new VehicleModel { Id = item.Id, Name = item.Name, Abrv = item.Abrv, MakeId = item.MakeId });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        private async void OnAddItem(object obj)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(NewVehicleModelPage)}?{nameof(NewVehicleModelViewModel.ItemId)}={ItemId}");
        }

        private string itemId;
        private string vehicleMakeName;
        private string vehicleMakeAbrv;
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string VehicleMakeName
        {
            get => vehicleMakeName;
            set => SetProperty(ref vehicleMakeName, value);
        }

        public string VehicleMakeAbrv
        {
            get => vehicleMakeAbrv;
            set => SetProperty(ref vehicleMakeAbrv, value);
        }

        public string ItemId
        {
            get
            {
                return itemId;
            }
            set
            {
                itemId = value;
                LoadItemId(value);
            }
        }

        public async void LoadItemId(string itemId)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = await BaseVehicleMakeDataStore.GetItemAsync(itemId);
                Id = item.Id;
                VehicleMakeName = item.Name;
                VehicleMakeAbrv = item.Abrv;
                Title = Id;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to Load Item");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NewVehicleModelViewModel:

```
namespace App3.ViewModels
{
    class NewVehicleModelViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
        private string text;
        private string description;
        private string itemId;

        public NewVehicleModelViewModel()
        {
            SaveCommand = new Command(OnSave, ValidateSave);
            CancelCommand = new Command(OnCancel);
            this.PropertyChanged +=
                (_, __) => SaveCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
            Text = ItemId;
            Description = ItemId;
        }

        private bool ValidateSave()
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)
                && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description);
        }
        public string ItemId
        {
            get
            {
                return itemId;
            }
            set
            {
                itemId = value;
                //LoadItemId(value);
            }
        }

        public async void LoadItemId(string itemId)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = await BaseVehicleMakeDataStore.GetItemAsync(itemId);
                ItemId = item.Id;
                //VehicleMakeName = item.Name;
                //VehicleMakeAbrv = item.Abrv;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to Load Item");
            }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get => text;
            set => SetProperty(ref text, value);
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get => description;
            set => SetProperty(ref description, value);
        }

        public Command SaveCommand { get; }
        public Command CancelCommand { get; }

        private async void OnCancel()
        {
            // This will pop the current page off the navigation stack
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }

        private async void OnSave()
        {
            VehicleModel newItem = new VehicleModel()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Name = Text,
                Abrv = Description,
                MakeId = ItemId
            };

            await BaseVehicleModelDataStore.AddItemAsync(newItem);

            // This will pop the current page off the navigation stack
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not appear to be doing anything to refresh or reload your data in VehicleMakeDetailViewModel after the new vehicle is added in NewVehicleModelViewModel

Comment: Yeah but I can see the new vehicle when I add it when I don't check if it has the same ID as the vehicleMaker and in fact I see that it doesn't have the same ID, I binded the id to a label in collectionview and its empty. The problem seems to be ID related

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the QueryProperty before NewVehicleModelViewModel class.
So class NewVehicleModelViewModel looks like this:

```
namespace App3.ViewModels
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(ItemId), nameof(ItemId))]
    class NewVehicleModelViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
... //other things are the same..
```

Comment: FWIW: What wasn't obvious unless someone read your code closely, is that these view models are for a `Shell` app. `QueryProperty` is a feature when using `Shell` navigation. In this case, showing the XAML page that uses these models, would have given more context to the question; made it easier to help you. (I mention as advice for future questions you ask.)

Comment: Also, when describing the problem, break it down into bite-size pieces. (Not a 12-line paragraph that no one will read carefully.) And relate it to code. "When I add a new vehicle blah-blah-blah" (then a code block showing the code that adds a new vehicle), I expected ... (ideally, a specific variable or XAML element, and what it should contain), but instead [this happened]. Then a new paragraph:  "I can see that the vehicle is added, but the id is not the one I want to set up, its empty." -- again, where in code? What variable should have the id?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Okay I will have that in mind, didn't know that this was Shell specific since this is basically my first project and I'm just learning. Thank you for your suggestion